# Cannot run "HelloWorld" monodroid application on my device

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

Helo.apk
and Hello-signed.apk (by vs2010 monodroid)(default monodroid app from template
I have lg android2.2 phone and i load by usb to my phone those files.
When i run it  i see "Unexpected error process Hello.apk")
In emulator device application works fine
Mycompilation config-debug all cpu

1. Should i install mono to my device?
2. Should i use another  build
   configuration(linking sd and user assemblies)
3. What is use shared
   libraries?

p.s i am using trial version of monodroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trial version of monodroid does not support pushing to phones, you will have to try your sample app on an emulator.

**Edit:**

Yes the emulator is pretty bad, I feel your pain - it's too the point where the trial version is almost useless. This is not monodroid's problem to solve though, even if it paints their product in a very bad picture. Developing and debugging on the phone with monodroid works actually much better.